# Error while trying to figure out dynamic typing

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can you please point out error in this code?

```
var top = "800px";
var pos = top.indexOf('px');
top = top.substring(0,pos);
console.log(top);
top+=5;
console.log(top);
top+="px";
console.log(top);
```

It doesn't compile no matter what I use, I'm trying to check if it will change type of top during operations.

Comment: And the error it gives is...?

Comment: depending on the compiler, it points out this error log: "Error: Blocked a frame with origin \"http://null.jsbin.com\" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Error (native)
    at lupavimebe.js:2:14
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.12.min.js:1:13891
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.12.min.js:1:10820"
(on JS Bin),
or that indexOf or substring is not a function. I relinked the lib, and wrote my own functions but they still don't work;

Comment: You should correct the `top = top.substring(0,pos);` line to `top = top.substring(0,pos)*1;` othwerwise you'll get the top value as 8005px. I doubt that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` is a [reserved variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) that you cannot override that points to the topmost window.

Just change the variable name to something else, like `topPos` and you're good to go:

```
var topPos = "800px";
var pos = topPos.indexOf('px');
topPos = topPos.substring(0,pos);
console.log(topPos);
topPos+=5;
console.log(topPos);
topPos+="px";
console.log(topPos);
```

However, `top` is only reserved in the *global scope*, so wrapping the code inside a function also solves the issue:

```
function run() {
  var top = "800px";
  var pos = top.indexOf('px');
  top = top.substring(0,pos);
  console.log(top);
  top+=5;
  console.log(top);
  top+="px";
  console.log(top);
}
run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a couple of minor changes:

- Changed `top` to `top1`.  This was to get past the fact that `top` was already defined in the sandbox here and couldn't be used.
- Modified one line to cast `top1` to a number before adding `5` so we got numeric addition.

```js
var top1 = "800px";
console.log(top1);

var pos = top1.indexOf('px');
top1 = top1.substring(0,pos);
console.log(top1);
// Force top back to being a number
top1 = +top1 + 5;
console.log(top1);
top1+="px";
console.log(top1);
```